# How can I fix the error in logging (config file)

Tags: python

I'm facing an error and I don't know why..
(The python file and the config file are in the same location.)

The python file is as follows

```
import logging
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.debug('debug')
logger.info('info')
logger.warning('warning')
logger.error('error')
logger.critical('critical')
```

The config file is as follows

```
[logger_root]
level = NOTSET
handlers = 

[logger_infoLogger]
level = INFO
handlers = simpleHandler
qualname = __main__
propagate = 1


[handler_simpleHandler]
class = StreamHandler
formatter = simpleFormatter
args = (sys.stdout,)


[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format = %(asctime)s - %(time)s - %(levelname)-8s - %(message)s
datefmt =
```

The error is as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/logging.py", line 1, in <module>
    import logging
  File "D:/Python/logging.py", line 2, in <module>
    import logging.config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'logging.config'; 'logging' is not a package
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script file is named `logging.py`, which makes it shadow the builtin `logging` module. Renaming your script file should do.

Comment: Nicely spotted.

Comment: Thanks! It's solved but now I faced another problem..

Answer (score 0):

try by replacing the first code to this and rename the file logging.conf

```
from logging import *
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.debug('debug')
logger.info('info')
logger.warning('warning')
logger.error('error')
logger.critical('critical')
```